# Unable to access method in arraylist class from other classes in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have 2 class files in my simple project - sorry another newbee here!

But I get a compilation error on the last part where I am trying to print the hopefully stored configuration settings from a file for my project that will be referred to throughout the project.
The file is just rows of values like this 'ButtonConfig,8,V,NULL,bunny,mpg'

I basically want to be able to used the contents of this arraylist to dynamicly set up the configuration of a Raspberry pi GPO pins i.e. for the above values button attached to GPO pin 8 will play video (V) "<..other value...>_bunny.mpg"

Any help greatly appreciated - just telling me why I can't access the getExtension method would be nice!

Contents of first java file is -

```
package bpunit;

public class ButtonConfig {
   private String keyword;
   private String gponumber;
   private String buttontype;
   private String language;
   private String filename;
   private String extension;

   public String getKeyword() {
      return keyword;
   }
   public void setKeyword(String keyword) {
      this.keyword = keyword;
   }

   ...............

   public String getExtension() {
     return extension;
   }

   public void setExtension(String extension) {
     this.extension = extension;
   }

}
```

The second contains this -

```
package bpunit;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class Read_ini {
    public void Read_ini_toObject() 
    {
    String csvFileToRead = "configs/BPUnit.properties";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line;
    String splitBy = ",";
    List buttonList = new ArrayList();

    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFileToRead));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            // split on comma(',')
            String[] buttonconfig = line.split(splitBy);

            // create button object to store values
            ButtonConfig buttonObject = new ButtonConfig();

            // add values from csv to car object
            buttonObject.setKeyword(buttonconfig[0]);
            buttonObject.setGponumber(buttonconfig[1]);
            buttonObject.setButtontype(buttonconfig[2]);
            buttonObject.setLanguage(buttonconfig[3]);
            buttonObject.setFilename(buttonconfig[4]);
            buttonObject.setExtension(buttonconfig[5]);
            // adding button object to a list
            buttonList.add(buttonObject);

        }
        // print values stored in buttonList
        printButtonList(buttonList);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           System.out.print(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
           System.out.print(e);
        } finally {
           if (br != null) {
               try {
                   br.close();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   System.out.print(e);
               }
           }
       }
    }

    public void printButtonList(List buttonListToPrint) {
        for (int i = 0; i < buttonListToPrint.size(); i++) {            

        // THE LINE BELOW FAILS - getExtension() does not exist 
        // and all other attempts give me pointer references 
        //instead of the text //

            System.out.println(buttonListToPrint.get(i).getExtension());        

           }
      } 

   }
```

Comment: Change `List buttonList = new ArrayList();` to `List<ButtonConfig> buttonList = new ArrayList<ButtonConfig>();` and also in `printButtonList` method, the argument should be `List<ButtonConfig> buttonListToPrint`

Comment: @svasa As of Java 7 you don't need to specify the generic type on the RHS when initializing.

Comment: Thanks svasa and all others. Worked a dream and helped me understand it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the parameterized type `ButtonConfig` to your `ArrayList`.  It ends up being `List<ButtonConfig>` instead of just `List`.

```
package bpunit;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class Read_ini {
    public void Read_ini_toObject() 
    {
    String csvFileToRead = "configs/BPUnit.properties";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line;
    String splitBy = ",";
    List<ButtonConfig> buttonList = new ArrayList<ButtonConfig>();

    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFileToRead));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            // split on comma(',')
            String[] buttonconfig = line.split(splitBy);

            // create button object to store values
            ButtonConfig buttonObject = new ButtonConfig();

            // add values from csv to car object
            buttonObject.setKeyword(buttonconfig[0]);
            buttonObject.setGponumber(buttonconfig[1]);
            buttonObject.setButtontype(buttonconfig[2]);
            buttonObject.setLanguage(buttonconfig[3]);
            buttonObject.setFilename(buttonconfig[4]);
            buttonObject.setExtension(buttonconfig[5]);
            // adding button object to a list
            buttonList.add(buttonObject);

        }
        // print values stored in buttonList
        printButtonList(buttonList);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           System.out.print(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
           System.out.print(e);
        } finally {
           if (br != null) {
               try {
                   br.close();
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   System.out.print(e);
               }
           }
       }
    }

    public void printButtonList(List<ButtonConfig> buttonListToPrint) {
        for (int i = 0; i < buttonListToPrint.size(); i++) {            

        // THE LINE BELOW FAILS - getExtension() does not exist 
        // and all other attempts give me pointer references 
        //instead of the text //

            System.out.println(buttonListToPrint.get(i).getExtension());        

           }
      } 

   }
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason why the compilation is failing is because when you add an object to the `ArrayList` it is upcast as an object of the class `Object`. Now when you extract it you simply have to typecast it back to the original type. so all you have to do is this :

```
public void printButtonList(List buttonListToPrint) {
        for (int i = 0; i < buttonListToPrint.size(); i++) {            

        // THE LINE BELOW FAILS - getExtension() does not exist 
        // and all other attempts give me pointer references 
        //instead of the text 
            ButtonConfig buttonObject =(ButtonConfig)buttonListToPrint.get(i);
            System.out.println(buttonObject.getExtension());        

           }
      }
```

Or as mentioned in the comments and answers above you could use `generics` and create an List of type `ButtonConfig`

```
public void Read_ini_toObject() 
    {
    String csvFileToRead = "configs/BPUnit.properties";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line;
    String splitBy = ",";
    List<ButtonConfig> buttonList = new ArrayList<ButtonConfig>();
```

and pass it in the function  `printButtonList`

```
public void printButtonList(List<ButtonConfig> buttonListToPrint) {
        for (int i = 0; i < buttonListToPrint.size(); i++) {            

        // THE LINE BELOW FAILS - getExtension() does not exist 
        // and all other attempts give me pointer references 
        //instead of the text                
System.out.println(buttonListToPrint.get(i).getExtension());  



           }
      }
```

Comment: Probably because you got it wrong in your original answer.

Comment: Okay then it would be great if some one could explain what is it that I have got wrong..... never too late to learn :)

Comment: You suggested to cast instead of using generics. This eliminates type safety, is old (Java 1.4), and makes the code less readable since you don't know what type the list contains.

Comment: aah ! my original intention was to explain what was actually happening... but yes I wasn't aware the best practice you mentioned. thanks